# Open CSV: open csv how to show quote character only one field

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, opencsv

I'm using OpenCsv library to create a .csv file in my Spring Boot application.
I need to put double quotaion symbol at the beginning and the end of just one field avoiding in the rest.

Here is that field named **description** that I want not to avoid **"**,

```
"\"" + description.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("\r","") + "\""
```

Here is my CSVWriter implementation,

```
StatefulBeanToCsv<DtoClass> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<DtoClass>(writer)
                .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                .withMappingStrategy(mapStrategy)
                .withSeparator(',')
                .build();

beanToCsv.write(dtoList);
```

But when I see in the result .csv file the library adds an additional " in the beginning and the end,

For ex:
The string I'm passing:

```
"Export Logs and save it for future reference."
```

What it writes in the resulted .csv file,

```
""Export Logs and save it for future reference.""
```

How can I avoid having this extra double quote?

My Environment: Spring Boot 2.2.4 | Java 8 | com.opencsv:opencsv:5.1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible to change the library but it is easier in jackson-dataformat-csv

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version></dependency>

CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(objects).withHeader();
schema = schema..withoutQuoteChar();
```